# Why can not copy for windows 7 to VIM?

Tags: vim, windows-7

What would be the commands to be able to do CTRL + V on gVim?

In OS X I can copy text into vim, but on Windows I'm not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to one of the following instead of setting up custom shortcuts:

1. Paste from register:

   > <kbd>"</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
2. Paste using middle mouse button
3. Paste using context menu

EDIT:

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/680271/562935) answer you might need to have the clipboard set to unnamed to get register pasting to work.

> `set clipboard=unnamed`

Comment: Only "+ p does not work in mac or win...

Comment: @AndersonJuhasc according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/680271/562935) answer you might need to `set clipboard=unnamed`

Answer (score 2):

From the vim [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html):

> mswin.vim
>
> To use the standard MS-Windows way of CTRL-X, CTRL-C and
>   CTRL-V, use the $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim script.  You could add this line
>   to your _vimrc file:  source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim

Answer (score 2):

While you can set up key bindings as Otiel suggests, I think it might be more useful to understand how copy and paste works in Vim, and learn what those commands actually mean.

The cut, copy and paste commands in Vim (`d`, `y` and `p`) work with so-called *registers* which hold the text last cut or copied. By default, they use the unnamed register `""`, while the system clipboard is the `"+` register.

You can prefix commands with a register to that one instead. So, to copy from Vim to Windows, use `"+y`, and to paste from Windows, use `"+p`.

You also have 26 registers named `"a` to `"z` which you can use for anything you want. This can be very useful when doing complex editing operations.

There are more special registers as well, for more info, see `:help registers`.

Comment: Using '"+ y' in OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `vimrc` file (should be located under `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc`):

```
" CTRL-X = cut
vnoremap <C-X> "+x
" CTRL-C = copy
vnoremap <C-C> "+y
" CTRL-V = paste
map <C-V> "+gP
cmap <C-V> <C-R>+
exe 'inoremap <script> <C-V>' paste#paste_cmd['i']
exe 'vnoremap <script> <C-V>' paste#paste_cmd['v']
imap <S-Insert> <C-V>
vmap <S-Insert> <C-V>
```

Or use the `p` command in vim to paste the content of the clipboard.

Comment: ... that is sooo wrong ...